# What causes mold on brand new porcelain tile--literally after only 4 well-ventilated showers with fan on?

Tags: shower, mold

I just had a brand new addition to my house constructed including a new bedroom and master bathroom installed.  All went well with two caveats:  (1) there was substantial flooding in the house near the shower area from an unsealed roof cut (2) there were some leaks in the walls near the shower from the new windows (contractor's installation fault), and (3) there was some minor flooding in the one shower wall at one point due to contractor forgetting to shut off the water and cutting some lines.  We also just experienced the wettest winter in 5-10 years in No. CA. Anyway, we have now used the shower ONLY 4 TIMES (with window open and fan on) and there is already significant blackening (mold-looking) on the porcelain tile.  The tile store says this shouldn't happen.  Contractor is claiming no knowledge.  It doesn't make sense to us how this could even happen.

[Numerous locations like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBB2G.jpg)  [image: And this]

Comment: I bet the fan is "on" but it's not hooked up or it's blocked. Can you turn it on and find it outside? Put a piece of paper over the inlet opening and see if it sucks it up.

Comment: Is that smooth tile? It looks like travertine in this picture. Can you post a clean tile for reference?

Comment: Fan is on an it works.  It now appears this is NOT mold, but part of the product.  Funny that only one of their display items and then it was very mild compared to the one I posted.  (I'd post a picture but I don't see how.)  Anyway, the good news is that it won't get worse.  The bad news is, some greater attention to detail by the contractor and owner could have created a much better end product.